# send varible to js file from routes nodejs

Tags: node.js

this code in routes.js.

```
    app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.user == null){
        res.redirect('/');
    }   else{
        AM.getAllCategories( function(e, categories){
        res.render('home', {
            title : 'Control Panel',
            classification : CF,
            udata : req.session.user,
            categ : categories
        });
        })
    }
});
```

"getAllCategories" function put in categories varibale all the database data.
after i send the "categ" varible to home, but when i try to use the varibale in home.js the varibale is undefined.

how i can send the varible to home.js?

when i use the varible in home.pug it's working.

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send values to the client side, the client first has to request for data.  This is because all server-client relationships are request and response based.  Therefore, in order for you to send data to the home.js(on the client side), the client side has to send an XML Request to routes.js(the server).

This can be accomplished on by adding the following code to the client side.

```
// you must call this function from home.js so that the server may send back the data.
function loadData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        data = this.responseText; // This will be the variable that receives the data from the server
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "requestedURL", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

You can learn more about this server-client relationship in the links below.

```
[Nodejs]: https://nodejs.org/ja/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/ 
[W3schools]: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_response.asp 
[Nodejs]: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/
```